# What is the correct way to fetch data and pass it to a route with react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my App.js I have the following routes:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Home palettes={this.state.palettes}/>}/>
    <Route exact path='/palette/:id' render={(urlParams) => <Palette palettes={this.state.palettes} urlParams={urlParams}/>}/> 
</Switch>
```

I'm fetching the data and updating it on the state:

```
  async componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    const response = await axios.get(API + DEFAULT_QUERY);  

    this.setState({
      palettes: [...response.data],
      isLoading:false
    });
  }
```

The thing is that if I go direct to the url '/palette/:id', componentDidMount is not triggered. How can I fetch the data in a way it can be passed to the routes and still get the data if I go direct to the route url?

Comment: why is not triggered? Can you provide working online example of the problem?

Comment: Here is the online example https://codesandbox.io/s/github/lucas-mdiniz/color-palette. If you click in a palette the code renders normally, but if you reload it the data is missing. I think that react router do not trigger it when going to another route.

Comment: you example is working with local server: http://localhost:

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the page after going into an palette url?

Comment: Can you give remote access through anydesk or TeamViewer?

Comment: You example will not work without server side that developed on your dev machine or  make a mock-up data of the fetch

Comment: My, bad. I forgot about the server running the API. But I found the problem, the route '/palette/:id' is rendered before the App.js component is mounted when going direct to the URL. I'm trying to find a workaround for this one.

Comment: @Oleg Just found a way and posted it as a answer. If you know a better way please let me know. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the thing was that for react-router componentDidMount() is triggered first in the child routes and after in the parent route, so the problem was the logic in my code.

The solution that I used is to check if the props that receive the data from the API fetch is empty, and if not I show some Loading, if there is data I render it. It's working because the child route also re-renders after the state changes in the parent component.

I still don't know if it is the best way for doing this, but it's working for now and I've learnt a little bit more about React lifecycle methods.